# Convert image from webcam to gray scale opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to openCV. I need to convert Mat from webcam to gray scale, but nothing happens I still see the RGB colored image.

```
capWebCam.read(matOriganal);

cv::Mat im_gray;
cv::cvtColor(matOriganal,im_gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
QImage qim_gray((uchar *)im_gray.data, im_gray.cols, im_gray.rows,
                    im_gray.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
ui->lOriginal->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qim_gray));
```

Could you, please, help me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very strange:

```
QImage::Format_RGB888
```

You are basically telling Qt that your image is stored as RGB with 8 bits for each channel, but your actual image is gray scale (one channel, 8 bit).

One simple solution is to simply convert your gray image back to RGB.

```
cv::cvtColor(matOriganal,im_gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat im_gray_rgb;
cv::cvtColor(im_gray,im_gray_rgb,CV_GRAY2RGB);
QImage qim_gray((uchar *)im_gray_rgb.data, im_gray_rgb.cols, im_gray_rgb.rows,
                    im_gray_rgb.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Even though the data is stored as RGB, it will still be gray. This of course means that you do an additional, and unnecessary copy.

The other option would be to not use `QImage::Format_RGB888`, but `QImage::Format_Indexed8`, but that might mean you need to specify a colormap. I have not tried that, so I don't know.